# java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException in RC5 implementation

Tags: java, cryptography

I would like to use RC5 encryption in my app with other word sizes and round numbers than default. I used [this implementation as a provider](https://www.flexiprovider.de/javadoc/flexiprovider/docs/de/flexiprovider/core/rc5/package-summary.html) but when I call it I get:

```
java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Illegal parameters
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.checkCryptoPerm(Cipher.java:1037)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1367)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1301)
    at asymetric.cipher.RC5moje.encrypt(RC5moje.java:87)
    at asymetric.cipher.RC5DES.main(RC5DES.java:25)
```

This is my code:

```
import de.flexiprovider.api.keys.SecretKey;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import de.flexiprovider.core.FlexiCoreProvider;
import de.flexiprovider.core.rc5.RC5KeyGenerator;
import de.flexiprovider.core.rc5.RC5ParameterSpec;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.Security;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;

public class RC5moje {

    private int roundNumer;
    private int wordSize;

    private SecretKey key;
    private RC5ParameterSpec RC5params;
    private Cipher rc5;

   public RC5moje(int roundNumer, int wordSize) {
        this.roundNumer = roundNumer;
        this.wordSize = wordSize;

        Security.addProvider(new FlexiCoreProvider());
        this.RC5params = new RC5ParameterSpec(roundNumer, wordSize);
        try {
            this.rc5 = Cipher.getInstance("RC5", "FlexiCore");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RC5moje.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RC5moje.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RC5moje.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        RC5KeyGenerator rC5KeyGenerator = new RC5KeyGenerator();
        this.key = rC5KeyGenerator.generateKey();

    }

    public void encrypt(String inFile, String outFile) {
        try {

            rc5.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, RC5params);

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inFile);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, rc5);

            byte[] block = new byte[8];
            int i;
            while ((i = fis.read(block)) != -1) {
                cos.write(block, 0, i);
            }
            cos.close();

        } catch (InvalidKeyException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RC5moje.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            Logger.getLogger(RC5moje.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RC5moje.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    public void decrypt(String inFile, String outFile) {

        try {
            rc5.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key,RC5params);

            FileInputStream fis;

            fis = new FileInputStream(inFile);

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, rc5);

            byte[] block = new byte[8];
            int i;

            while ((i = cis.read(block)) != -1) {
                fos.write(block, 0, i);
            }
            fos.close();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RC5moje.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RC5moje.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RC5moje.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I initialize this class like this: 
`RC5moje rc5 = new RC5moje(12, 32);`
so I think this is not a problem with values as those are default but perhaps I'm incorrectly creating RC5Params?

EDIT:
In the sources of de.flexiprovider.core.rc5.RC5ParameterSpec I found that you can't set them to incorrect values:

```
public RC5ParameterSpec(int numRounds, int wordSize) {
    if ((numRounds < 8) || (numRounds > 127)) {
        this.numRounds = DEFAULT_NUM_ROUNDS;
    } else {
        this.numRounds = numRounds;
    }

    if ((wordSize != 16) && (wordSize != 32) && (wordSize != 64)) {
        this.wordSize = DEFAULT_WORD_SIZE;
    } else {
        this.wordSize = wordSize;
    }
    }
```

EDIT2:
So after mingling with my code I decided to try Bouncy Castle as a provider and that solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the FlexiCore specific `RC5ParameterSpec`, try and use the [Java JCA one instead](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/RC5ParameterSpec.html).

Comment: I tried your solution but still got the same error. I didn't know what should I set `version` parameter of `javax.crypto.spec.RC5ParameterSpec` to and tried couple of random (0,1,2,3,5) ints but to no avail. I'm still getting InvalidAlghoritmParametersException.

Comment: I hope I can test when I get home. This is strange, I felt pretty sure that this was what was going wrong.